# 500 internal server error php, how to solve?

Tags: php, internal-server-error

I created a simple php webcrawler on my webhost, but after a while it gives a 500 internal server error.
Assuming the coding and permissions are good.. what can I do about it?

I upgraded from shared hosting to VPS hosting, but it seems to give the error even sooner. I am really lost here.

Comment: Are you able to show the code here.

Comment: htaccess can be set uncorrectly, you can have error in PHP script, whatever... see error log.

Comment: You can easily get a 500 internal server error if the modules for PHP are specifically compiled for the version that you are running.

Comment: There are too many things it could be. Check your logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

-Enable the error reporting from php.ini file or by functions like

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

- Disable .htaccess file
- Check the error_log